# Jquery autocomplete show two rows from mysql in one row

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I have a mysql table with multiple rows

```
ID, country, city, region
```

I have a search working with jquery-ui autocomplete, which currently autocompletes city searches like so:

```
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    $return_arr = array();

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";port=8889;dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT city,country FROM location WHERE city LIKE :term LIMIT 10');
        $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $return_arr[] =  $row['city'];

        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }



    echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
```

I would like to display the country next to the city, so `Los Angeles` would become `Los Angeles, US`

Comment: Really? can't handle a basic string operation? `$arr[] = "{$row['city']}, {$row['country']}"`

Comment: Really? cant answer without sarcasm? You can use $return_arr[] = $row['city'].", ".$row['country'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php you can append a string by using a '.' For example:

```
$mystring = 'part one' . 'part two';

echo $mystring; //-> will product: part onepart wo
```

You can also let php interpret a string to delimiting with '"' (double quotes)

```
$myvar = "boat";
$mystring = "One day I'll buy a {$myvar}";

echo $mystring; //-> will produce: One day I'll buy a boat
```

The below should work ok. Good luck!

```
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    $return_arr = array();

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";port=8889;dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT city,country FROM location WHERE city LIKE :term LIMIT 10');
        $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $return_arr[] =  $row['city'] . ', ' . $row['country'];

        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }



    echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
```

Another alternative way to solve this would be to append the string in your SQL

```
SELECT CONCAT(city, ', ', country) AS location FROM location WHERE city LIKE :term LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I didn't realize it was that simple, anyways, great answer with multiple valid options, I will keep these in mind. Thank you !

Comment: Is there any way, when clicking something in the auto complete so that that it does NOT add the `, Countrycode` to the text field ?

Comment: That you would handle with your autocomplete or typeahead implementation. Assuming you're using one of those. Most likely it's best to create a new post detailing what it is exactly you're trying to achieve.